# Yammer WebPart for SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, web-part, yammer

Does anyone have any idea where I'd be able to get the SharePoint 2007 Yammer Web Part from?  I appereciate that it's been retired but it's something that I'd like to make use off prior to my planned SharePoint upgrade.  The previous links now redirect to the AppStore Yammer Application for SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Yammer for SharePoint 2010 – FAQs](http://success.yammer.com/success/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2013/10/Yammer-For-SharePoint-2010-FAQs.pdf) (last update: 03.10.2013), the yammer web part should be unavailable for SharePoint 2007:

> 1. Is there support for MOSS 2007? As of July 1, 2013, support for MOSS 2007 ends. No support will be available after that date.

The link [Yammer SharePoint 2007 Web Part](http://www.yammer.com/company/sharepoint2007) is not valid anymore and official yammer web part for SharePoint 2007 is unavailable for download.

### Third party yammer web parts

http://spark.codeplex.com/

Comment: I appreciate that its out of support, that doesn't make my reason for wanting to use it invalid.  I've seen the Spark utility but it's not really relevant for what I'm after.  I'm just wondering / hoping if anyone in the community had a copy before it was taken down.

Comment: If it isn't supported anymore by Yammer, this is a valid answer even if it isn't what you want to hear. You should probably reach out to Yammer directly to see if it is available, they can probaly get it to you even if it isn't publicly available anymore, just don't expect support, by their own admission it isn't supported.

Comment: MS (unless I'm mistaken) continue to have unsupported products within their various sites and communities available, stuff like MS Money, the Expression range and misc sunset release products.  All I'm saying with the above is that I'm aware its out of support and has been intentionally removed but I'm wanting to ask if anyone within the SP community has a copy of it lying around.  The SharePoint 2003 Page Capture Web Part (for example) got some mileage in later editions of SharePoint, I'm just after something similar.  If no-one has a copy in the next week or so, I'll mark this accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Yammer Embed with a content editor web part to place yammer content into SharePoint 2007.  See this:  https://developer.yammer.com/connect/

Comment: I've  been doing this a while now but at the time I wanted to know if the 2007 Web Part was more elegant.

Comment: If you want to have better styling (and more coding), you can always fall back to using the REST interface to get json back and bind that via your favorite javascript library.